# Under sink bowl is leaking

Tags: sink, leaking

What to do? How to stop the leaking under bathroom sink bowl?

[image]

Comment: Could be a few causes of leaks, but to start with, take a wrench, and tighten the connections. If they are not fully tight this may do it for you. if not, you need to figure out if it is a tap leak or drain leak, and then may have to solder/crimp or glue parts,... or replace rubber o-rings or teflon tape. Start with basics tighten all and see if it's fixed. If not locate leak and add pictures of the leaking location

Comment: Really need pics of the area leaking. Not the sink bowl and vanity.

Comment: There are at least a dozen different possible causes of leakage here.

Comment: Thank you all. The leakage I noticed is from the bowl area so that's why I posted that photo. I don't see leakage under the cabinet where the piping is. Only around the platform by the bowl area

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If there are plastic fittings just under the cabinet, do _not_ use a wrench on them! They're designed to work properly when hand tight, or wrench tightened no more than about 1/4 turn. If it's still leaking at that point, _something else_ is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

If you're correct that it's leaking from under the bowl on to the cabinet, then the problem's with the drain flange. The flange could be loose and just needs to be tightened or the gasket/putty between the flange and bowl could be bad and needs to be redone.